# How to parse a swift string to get out data

Tags: ios, string

I'm using Factual API to obtain information about businesses. For the place hours, I get back a single string:

`"{\"monday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"friday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"sunday\":[[\"00:00\",\"1:00\"],[\"10:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"tuesday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"thursday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"saturday\":[[\"00:00\",\"1:00\"],[\"10:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"wednesday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]]}"`

I've tried several things to break this up and I'm banging my head. Any ideas how I can parse this string to be able to get open/close times by day to determine if a place is currently open? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: What have your tried so far? I'd try some sort of regex.

Comment: The string is valid JSON. Can you show how you're getting it? You should probably be putting the data in a dictionary instead of a string.

Comment: So the data is returned to me in a string, it would be easier with a dictionary for sure. I've tried componentsSeperatedByString to get little pieces, but it just is hard to crack this nut. What kind of regex would help me out? Thanks a lot for your responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to `NSData`, then to a `Dictionary`:

```
let string = "{\"monday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"friday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"sunday\":[[\"00:00\",\"1:00\"],[\"10:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"tuesday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"thursday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"saturday\":[[\"00:00\",\"1:00\"],[\"10:00\",\"23:59\"]],\"wednesday\":[[\"11:00\",\"23:59\"]]}"

let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let dictionary = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [String : AnyObject]

print(dictionary["monday"]![0][0]) //11:00
print(dictionary["monday"]![0][1]) //23:59
```

Of course, it would be a bit easier to get it as a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!